# Syntax errors in perl header files when compiling Oracle Pro*C

Tags: linux, oracle, perl, compiler-errors

I am migrating Oracle Pro*C programs from Solaris (Sparc) to RHEL (Intel) some of which include Perl so have included the Perl header directory in the compile command (see below). I am getting errors reporting syntax errors in the perl header files. I am using a very recent copy of perl (v5.38.2) are these perl bugs or am I doing something wrong here such as using a multi-threaded version of perl instead of a single threaded version. any help would be appreciated.

Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
Perl version = (v5.38.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15) (GCC)
Oracle version 19.19.0.0.0
Pro*C/C++: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jan 24 13:40:57 2024

If I run this from the command line, I get the syntax errors below

```
proc sqlcheck=semantics  common_parser=yes  parse=full userid=sms411/dfts code=ANSI_C dbms=v8 MODE=ORACLE CHAR_MAP=VARCHAR2 unsafe_null=yes define=__x86_64__ sys_include=$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public sys_include=/usr/include sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include sys_include=/opt/mnt1/users/builder/GLOSSI_BUILD/include include=$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public include=$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public include=$ORACLE_HOME/lib include=/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE ltype=short -I/opt/mnt1/users/builder/GLOSSI_BUILD/include iname=dr_FTP.pc

Syntax error at line 400, column 34, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:
Error at line 400, column 34 in file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_
64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h
extern PERL_THREAD_LOCAL (void *)PL_current_context;
.................................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "PL_current_context" when expecting one of t
he following:

   ; { , = ( [ auto, case, const, continue, enum, float, for,
   goto, ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIClobLocator,
   OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid,
   OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register, return,
   short, signed, sizeof, sql_cursor, static, switch, typedef,
   union, unsigned, uvarchar, varchar, void, volatile, while,
   an identifier, a typedef name, a precompiled header,
   a numeric constant, an immediate preprocessor command, begin,
   bind, character, close, exec sql var, fetch, identified,
   ifdef, ifndef, integer, into, scroll,
The symbol ";" was substituted for "PL_current_context" to continue.

Syntax error at line 661, column 29, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:
Error at line 661, column 29 in file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_
64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h
PERL_CALLCONV regexp_engine const *
............................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "const" when expecting one of the following:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "const" to continue.

Syntax error at line 941, column 28, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:
Error at line 941, column 28 in file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_
64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h
Perl_do_seek(pTHX_ GV *gv, Off_t pos, int whence)
...........................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "off64_t" when expecting one of the followin
g:

   ... auto, case, const, continue, enum, float, goto,
   ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, register, return, short, signed, sizeof,
   sql_cursor, static, switch, typedef, union, unsigned,
   varchar, void, volatile, while, an identifier,
   a typedef name, a precompiled header, a numeric constant,
   an immediate preprocessor command, begin, bind, character,
   exec sql var, fetch, identified, ifdef, ifndef, integer,
   into,
The symbol "float," was substituted for "off64_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 956, column 1, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:
Error at line 956, column 1 in file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_6
4-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h
Perl_do_sysseek(pTHX_ GV *gv, Off_t pos, int whence)
1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "Perl_do_sysseek" when expecting one of the
following:
...
other errors are in proto.h
...
Syntax error at line 3606, column 127, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:
Error at line 3606, column 127 in file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x8
6_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h
Perl_re_intuit_start(pTHX_ REGEXP * const rx, SV *sv, const char * const strbeg,
 char *strpos, char *strend, const U32 flags, re_scream_pos_data *data);

...
Syntax error at line 3616, column 93, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h:
Error at line 3616, column 93 in file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86
_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/proto.h
Perl_re_op_compile(pTHX_ SV ** const patternp, int pat_count, OP *expr, const re
gexp_engine *eng, REGEXP *old_re, bool *is_bare_re, const U32 rx_flags, const U3
2 pm_flags);
...
```

I have tried running the 'proc' statement from the command line and search for similar errors but with no luck

Update 25/01/24 as requested, below is a section of the .pc source file which contains the perl. It call a perl program named File_Transfer.pl which 'ftp's (I know we should not use that anymore and it is being changed) a file over to a remote server.

...

```
 static PerlInterpreter *my_perl ;


int Transfer_file(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {  printf("dr_FTP.pc Start Transfer_file \n");

        int t_argc = NULL;
        int fr_int = NULL;
        char *perl_arg[6];
        char *Plhome;

        char *t_argv[] = {"dr_FTP.so","/Dummy1/Dummy2/Dummy3/Dummy4/Dummy5/Dummy6/Dummy7/Dummy8/Dummy9/Dummy10/Dummy11/Dummy12"};
        Plhome= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *100);
        strcpy(Plhome , (char *)getenv("GLOSSI_HOME_CORE_LIB"));
        if (Plhome != NULL) {
                if ( strstr(Plhome,"File_Transfer.pl") == NULL ) {
                        strcat(Plhome,"/File_Transfer.pl");
                }
        }

        printf("Perl file Path is %s \n",Plhome);

        strcpy(t_argv[1],Plhome);

        perl_arg[0]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *50);
        perl_arg[1]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *50);
        perl_arg[2]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *50);
        perl_arg[3]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *50);
        perl_arg[4]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *50);
        perl_arg[5]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *50);

        strcpy(perl_arg[0],oratoc(v_rep));
        strcpy(perl_arg[1],oratoc(v_corp));
        strcpy(perl_arg[2],oratoc(v_crn));
        strcpy(perl_arg[3],oratoc(v_invnbr));
        strcpy(perl_arg[4],oratoc(v_prtn));
        strcpy(perl_arg[5],oratoc(v_server));

        perl_parse(my_perl,xs_init , t_argc, t_argv, (char **)NULL);

        perl_run(my_perl);

        call_argv("ftp_param", G_DISCARD , perl_arg);

        perl_destruct(my_perl);

        perl_free(my_perl);

        for( fr_int=0;fr_int<6;fr_int++)
        {
                free(perl_arg[fr_int]);
        }


return 1;

printf("dr_FTP.pc End Transfer_file \n");

} ...
```

If "include=/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE" is excluded from the proc command line arguments, then I get the below. Which I guess is due to the header files being included in the .pc file

```
Pro*C/C++: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jan 25 10:51:15 2024
Version 19.19.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /opt/mnt1/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Error at line 38, column 10 in file dr_FTP.pc
#include <EXTERN.h>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 41, column 9 in file dr_FTP.pc
#include<perl.h>
........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Syntax error at line 70, column 24, file dr_FTP.pc:
Error at line 70, column 24 in file dr_FTP.pc
static PerlInterpreter *my_perl ;
.......................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "*" when expecting one of the following:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "*" to continue.

Error at line 0, column 0 in file dr_FTP.pc
PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing
```

There is SQL embedded in the .pc file (example below) and it does not look like it would be easy to separate it out as the result of the queries get assigned to variables etc.

..

```
 EXEC SQL EXECUTE
    declare
       vRptNbr report_options.rpt_nbr%type;
       vStatus report_options.Status%type;
        a number;
    begin
       -- we need to find rpt_nbr and status of the component
       vRptNbr := CacheKeyPkg.GetRptNbr(:ch_id);
       vStatus := CacheKeyPkg.GetStatus(:ch_id);

      select ck.PRTN_CD,ck.CORP_NBR,ck.CRN,ck.COMPONENT_ID||'_'||ck.INV_NBR||decode(pr.file_type,'CSV','.csv','.pdf'),ck.INV_NBR into :v_prtn, :v_corp,:v_crn,:v_rep,:v_invnbr
      from CACHE_KEY ck,Pipeline_reports pr
      where ck.COMPONENT_ID = pr.RPT_NBR
      and   ck.CACHE_ID = :ch_id;

      :v_server := printpipe_monitor.get_param(:Req_id);
```

...

This code compiled ok on Sparc Solaris with the 'Oracle Developer Studio' cc compiler, however with a very old version of perl 5.8 and the Oracle 12 version of the 'proc' command.

Don't know what you think but could it be one of the following, unless you have some other options:

- Bug in the perl header file <= could try another version
- Bug in the 'proc' compiler
- Possible missing proc option

Thanks Håkon, I have looked at the '/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h' file around line 400 and found the below. Although I don't profess to understand all what the comment is saying, it might mean something to you

From thread.h

```
389 #if defined(PERL_THREAD_LOCAL) && !defined(PERL_GET_CONTEXT) && !defined(PERL_SET_CONTEXT) && !defined(__cplusplus)
390 /* Use C11 thread-local storage, where possible.
391  * Frustratingly we can't use it for C++ extensions, C++ and C disagree on the
392  * syntax used for thread local storage, meaning that the working token that
393  * Configure probed for C turns out to be a compiler error on C++. Great.
394  * (Well, unless one or both is supporting non-standard syntax as an extension)
395  * As Configure doesn't have a way to probe for C++ dialects, we just take the
396  * safe option and do the same as 5.34.0 and earlier - use pthreads on C++.
397  * Of course, if C++ XS extensions really want to avoid *all* this overhead,
398  * they should #define PERL_NO_GET_CONTEXT and pass aTHX/aTHX_ explicitly) */
399 #  define PERL_USE_THREAD_LOCAL
400 extern PERL_THREAD_LOCAL (void *)PL_current_context;
401
402 #  define PERL_GET_CONTEXT        PL_current_context
403
404 /* We must also call pthread_setspecific() always, as C++ code has to read it
405  * with pthreads (the #else side just below) */
406
```

Update:
I installed perl by downloading the source from cpan and then

tar -xzf perl-5.38.2.tar.gz
cd /tmp/perl-5.38.2

./Configure -des -Dprefix=/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2 -Dusethreads

make

make test

make install

All tests passed and running the command you asked gives the followin

```
perl -V:config_args
config_args='-des -Dprefix=/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2 -Dusethreads';

perl -V | grep thread
    archname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    config_args='-des -Dprefix=/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2 -Dusethreads'
    useithreads=define
    libs=-lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    PERL_INCLUDE="/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/site_perl/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

I am going to build a perl version which is just single threaded to see if that makes any difference.

I have noticed in some posts they refer to threads.h instead of thread.h - not sure if that is a typo.

One suggestion was to add ([_Thread_local storage class specifier in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289634/thread-local-storage-class-specifier-in-c))

#define of _Thread_local

I could try adding that to the proc command line  to see if it has any effect

Update 29/01/24
I compiles a single threaded version of the same release of perl and the original first error I was getting seems to have been removed. I am now left with the errors in perl.h (see below)

> proc sqlcheck=semantics  common_parser=yes  parse=full
> userid=sms411/dfts code=ANSI_C dbms=v8 MODE=ORACLE CHAR_MAP=VARCHAR2
> unsafe_null=yes define=**x86_64**
> sys_include=$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public sys_include=/usr/include
> sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include
> sys_include=/opt/mnt1/users/builder/GLOSSI_BUILD/include
> include=$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public include=$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public
> include=$ORACLE_HOME/lib ltype=short
> -I/opt/mnt1/users/builder/GLOSSI_BUILD/include include=/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE
> iname=dr_FTP.pc

This now gives the following errors

> Pro*C/C++: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jan 29 11:01:06 2024
> Version 19.19.0.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
> reserved.
>
> System default option values taken from:
> /opt/mnt1/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg
>
> Syntax error at line 6036, column 9, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6036, column 9 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x 86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> typedef regexp* (*regcomp_t) (pTHX_ char* exp, char* xend, PMOP* pm);
> ........1 PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "regexp" when expecting
> one of the following :
>
> auto, case, const, continue, enum, float, goto,    ulong_varchar,
> OCIBFileLocator OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,    OCIExtProcContext,
> OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,    OCIRaw, OCIString,
> register, return, short, signed, sizeof,    sql_cursor, static,
> switch, typedef, union, unsigned,    varchar, void, volatile, while,
> an identifier,    a typedef name, a precompiled header, a numeric
> constant,    an immediate preprocessor command, begin, bind,
> character, The symbol "float," was substituted for "regexp" to
> continue.
>
> Syntax error at line 6037, column 43, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6037, column 43 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/ x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> typedef I32     (*regexec_t) (pTHX_ regexp* prog, char* stringarg,
> ..........................................1 PCC-S-02201, Encountered
> the symbol "*" when expecting one of the following:
>
> , )
>
> Syntax error at line 6040, column 52, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6040, column 52 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/ x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> typedef char*   (*re_intuit_start_t) (pTHX_ regexp *prog, SV *sv,
> ...................................................1 PCC-S-02201,
> Encountered the symbol "*" when expecting one of the following:
>
> , )
>
> Syntax error at line 6043, column 49, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6043, column 49 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/ x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> re_scream_pos_data *d); ................................................1 PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "re_scream_pos_data" when expecting one of t he
> following:
>
> ... auto, case, const, continue, enum, float, goto,
> ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
> OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
> OCIRaw, OCIString, register, return, short, signed, sizeof,
> sql_cursor, static, switch, typedef, union, unsigned,    varchar,
> void, volatile, while, an identifier,    a typedef name, a precompiled
> header, a numeric constant,    an immediate preprocessor command,
> begin, bind, character,    exec sql var, fetch, identified, ifdef,
> ifndef, integer,    into, The symbol "float," was substituted for
> "re_scream_pos_data" to continue.
>
> Syntax error at line 6044, column 49, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6044, column 49 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/ x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> typedef SV*     (*re_intuit_string_t) (pTHX_ regexp *prog);
> ................................................1 PCC-S-02201,
> Encountered the symbol "*" when expecting one of the following:
>
> , )
>
> Syntax error at line 6046, column 9, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6046, column 9 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x 86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> typedef regexp* (*regdupe_t) (pTHX_ const regexp* r, CLONE_PARAMS
> *param); ........1 PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "regexp" when expecting one of the following :
>
> auto, case, const, continue, enum, float, goto,    ulong_varchar,
> OCIBFileLocator OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,    OCIExtProcContext,
> OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,    OCIRaw, OCIString,
> register, return, short, signed, sizeof,    sql_cursor, static,
> switch, typedef, union, unsigned,    varchar, void, volatile, while,
> an identifier,    a typedef name, a precompiled header, a numeric
> constant,    an immediate preprocessor command, begin, bind,
> character, The symbol "float," was substituted for "regexp" to
> continue.
>
> Syntax error at line 6046, column 49, file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h:
> Error at line 6046, column 49 in file
> /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2_st/lib/5.38.2/ x86_64-linux/CORE/perl.h
> typedef regexp* (*regdupe_t) (pTHX_ const regexp* r, CLONE_PARAMS
> *param); ................................................1 PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "*" when expecting one of the
> following:
>
> , ( ) [
>
> Error at line 0, column 0 in file dr_FTP.pc PCC-F-02102, Fatal error
> while doing C preprocessing

Seems there is a problem with the Oracle 19c proc command not recognising 'regexp' - does anyone have a solution or work around for this ?

###### Update 22/02/24

Below is an example of embedded perl in a c program which causes the errors (no need for the proc compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>

extern void xs_init();

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;


void ftp_perl()
{
printf("wrap_batch.pc start ftp_perl \n");

my_perl = perl_alloc();
        if (my_perl==NULL)
        {
                printf("XXXX..1.. Error in mem allocation.. perl_alloc \n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("XXXX..1.. No probs in mem allocation.. perl_alloc \n");
        }
perl_construct(my_perl);
perl_destruct(my_perl);
perl_free(my_perl);

printf("wrap_batch.pc end ftp_perl \n");
}
```

Using the following version of perl
perl -v
This is perl 5, version 38, subversion 2 (v5.38.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

if you try to compile this with the following:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -g -v -O -o rb_test.o rb_test.c `perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
```

You get the following errors

```
In file included from rb_test.c:7:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/perl.h:6066:44: warning: 'struct REGEXP' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 typedef void    (*regfree_t) (pTHX_ struct REGEXP* r);
                                            ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/perl.h:6188,
                 from rb_test.c:7:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:400:27: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
 extern PERL_THREAD_LOCAL (void *)PL_current_context;
                           ^~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/inline.h: In function 'Perl_mortal_getenv':
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:402:35: error: 'PL_current_context' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'Perl_get_context'?
 #  define PERL_GET_CONTEXT        PL_current_context
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:402:35: note: in definition of macro 'PERL_GET_CONTEXT'
 #  define PERL_GET_CONTEXT        PL_current_context
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/perl.h:207:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PERL_GET_THX'
 #  define dTHX  pTHX = PERL_GET_THX
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/inline.h:3324:5: note: in expansion of macro 'dTHX'
     dTHX;
     ^~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:402:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #  define PERL_GET_CONTEXT        PL_current_context
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:402:35: note: in definition of macro 'PERL_GET_CONTEXT'
 #  define PERL_GET_CONTEXT        PL_current_context
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/perl.h:207:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PERL_GET_THX'
 #  define dTHX  pTHX = PERL_GET_THX
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/inline.h:3324:5: note: in expansion of macro 'dTHX'
     dTHX;
     ^~~~
```

Trying to work out if these are coding, perl or gcc errors and what are the work arounds

Comment: *"Syntax error at line 400, column 34, file /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.38.2/lib/5.38.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/thread.h:"* : It appears that the compiler has a problem at [line 400 in thread.h](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/48d382667948f6a16c732c47791ca4be891a9bdb/thread.h#L400). Could you try to reorder lines in that file to find out more details about what the compiler has problems with?

Comment: Continuing from the previous comment: This could also be a C++ vs C issue (se the comment [starting at line 390](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/48d382667948f6a16c732c47791ca4be891a9bdb/thread.h#L390). Could you try determine the value of the macro `PERL_THREAD_LOCAL` at line 400?

Comment: Continuing.. : Maybe `PERL_THREAD_LOCAL` macro is equal to the `_Thread_local` storage class specifier? See https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/48d382667948f6a16c732c47791ca4be891a9bdb/config_h.SH#L5241 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14289634/2173773 ... and the proc compiler does not support it?

Comment: I will try to install "proc" compiler on my laptop (running Ubuntu 23.10) and try reproduce the error you get.

Comment: Seems like the precompiler download requires an oracle account: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/precompiler-downloads.html
So unfortunately, it seems I am not able to test the proc compiler

Comment: Thanks Håkon the proc does require an oracle database connection to compile. I am trying to work out what my options are now.

Comment: If you can send me the whole .pc file I can have a look at it. Maybe we can split it up into a .c file and a .pc file where the .pc file does not need to include `perl.h` ?

Comment: thanks again Håkon, I have sent you the file. Just let me know if you have any issues receiving it.