# Dereferencing pointer type when in sizeof()

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, types, dereference

I have following structure:

```
typedef struct _foo_t {
    int bar;
    float buzz;
    char quux[40];
} *const foo_t;
```

Is there a way to get the size of structure, like it's done via `sizeof(struct _foo_t)`, but using only name `foo_t`? I have tried `sizeof(*foo_t)`, but that does not compile.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: sizeof() is a compile-time calculation. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195386/why-is-sizeof-called-a-compile-time-operator

Comment: My guess is a parsing error, does foo_t obj; sizeof(*obj) work?

Comment: You are declaring a constant pointer, not pointer to const struct. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I expect that `sizeof(struct _foo_t)` is around 48 bytes. (platform dependent)

Comment: You declare foo_t as a typedef for a pointer to a structure. The idiomatic C approach is to declare a typedef for a structure, and then declare a typedef for the pointer to the structure.

Comment: @RealProgrammer57 "missing parentheses"

Comment: @Olaf yes, actually. I use constant pointers much everywhere. Making whole structure constant wasn't the goal, because then it would be immutable, and it's too expensive in my case to recreate state on each mutation.

Comment: @abelensky, sure I can calculate the size, but question was on how to let compiler do that work instead of me.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill I decided to follow OpenCL-like style in this particular project, where all non-primitive types are "implicit pointers".

Comment: @modchan: I presume you are very well aware there is a fundamental difference between them .. ? (no offense). To me the pointer typedef'ed `const` makes little sense (oh, I _do_ understand the reason to have such an argument `const`!). That way you have to have either two typedefs (how would do you alloc such a struct?), or have to ressort to the struct name as such anyway. Welcome to enlighten me!

Comment: @Olaf, for resulting types, as well for arguments I use `void foo_method(foo_t self);`, which boils down to `void foo_method(struct _foo_t *const self);`. When I need to initialize such a struct, which never happens outside of constructors, I define constructor as `foo_t foo_new(void);`, create `struct _foo_t *self;` inside, allocate and then return it.

Comment: Alternatively, I use `typedef struct _foo_t { ... } *const foo_t, *foo_m_t;`, with `foo_m_t` having the same use as plain `struct _foo_t *self`.

Comment: @Olaf so the whole point of question was to wrap structure allocation in a macro with no dependencies on variable names or such, given only type. Sorry if this looks like totally newbie question.

Comment: @modchan: Well, so you actually _do_ revert to using the struct type explicitly, too, as I suspected in a comment below. Well, not my kind of style, I stick with mine, but thanks anyway for explaining. Oh, you are aware name suffix `_t` should not be used for custom types. The same for `_` prefix (note that all new keywords are added that way). I already got the intention. You actually _do_ use the pointer like a handle! But: why using a macro? That would require to exhibit the interior anyway in a header, breaking opacity (well, the typedef above already does actually).

Comment: @Olaf I know about `_t` suffixes being reserved by system. All my identifiers use custom prefix, so I hope there won't be clash with system-provided identifiers. Regarding opacity — actual scheme is a bit more complex. There are two interfaces — public and private. Public interface only has `typedef void *foo_t`. Private interface has full structure definitions, as well as instantiating macros, and "borderline" functions cast `foo_t` to `internal_foo_t` before use. To user that remains opaque pointer. No macros are published, as user will never instantiate those objects directly via `struct`.

Comment: Macro in question is like `#define ALLOC(type)  struct _internal##type *self; if ((self = malloc(sizeof(*self))) == NULL) { perror("alloc"#type); abort(); }`. I wanted to remove variable declaration from it and leave only `malloc()`, so it can be more "pure".

Comment: Sorry, but that sounds getting worse. `void *`? Hey, be nice to your compiler! Why do you actively defy type checking? Well, your project, I prefer to have as few typecasts as possible (and `void *` is one of the worst imo). You actively prevent the outside to typecheck what goes inside (and vice versa). Note that C checks type compatibility by equivalence, not by name as Python and C++ do! `typedef void *a, *b` are compatible types in C (simply put).

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe you can do this directly. You'll need to define an intermediate typedef if you want to do this:

```
typedef struct _foo_t {
    int bar;
    float buzz;
    char quux[40];
} foo_t;

typedef foo_t *const foo_tp;

// sizeof(foo_t) should work
```

Dereferencing a type doesn't really make sense in C. You can dereference a variable, but not a type. In C++, you can do these kinds of type operations using templates, but that's not really applicable since you indicate the C tag.

You could also declare a dummy variable of the appropriate type to invoke `sizeof` on an expression:

```
foo_tp f;
// sizeof(*f) should work
```

Comment: There's no need for 2 typedefs.  Last line `} foo_t, *const foo_tp;` will do it. NB, types ending in `_t` are reserved in the standard for use by standard libraries.

Comment: @Gene: I searched in the standard about `_t`suffix, as I also think so, but I cannot find it. Would be great if you can give me a pointer (not `void *`, please;-).

Comment: The `_t` suffix is reserved by the POSIX standard, *not* the C standard.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by using a compound literal like this:

```
sizeof(*(foo_t){NULL})
```

Comment: I would expect he already know this. How would he define such a struct actually (or allocate it).

Comment: In this case it doesn't make sense to do this, I guess. You are right.

Comment: Well... I don't see an advantage in using typedefs for pointer in most places anyway (see my answer). But that is not my code, so...

Comment: Fully agree with you.

Comment: Delete the second version. C should use NULL (and for C++ they apparently noticed the need for an explicit NULL-pointer, too - bad enough, only after they removed the necessity for using `NULL` in the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

`foo_t` is a `typedef`, so it is like a type.

`*foo_t` is not a valid expression, because you cannot dereference a type.

Since it is not a valid expression, you cannot get its size.

It is as writing:

```
typedef int * pointer_to_int_type;

size_t a = sizeof(*pointer_to_int_type);
```

Comment: You can very well get the size of a type, not just an expression.

Comment: `auto`? Long time not seen ... (but I do get the point for using it .. like that)

Comment: `auto` is very well standard C, too. Actually, it has ben there since K&R. Leave it, it tags teh variable as being inside a function, not static/global without writing the func-body.

Comment: @Olaf Its meaning in C is not the same as in C++. In C++ auto is type deduction. In C it means a local variable. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192547/where-is-the-c-auto-keyword-used

Comment: Ok. Well, I interpreted it the C way. However you meant it, it did work pretty well (even if by chance - just take that medal and sh* u* ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a type name as an operand (not only for sizeof), as an expression requires to have a type (in C, types are no first class citizens like in full OO-languages like Python). However, you can use a *type-name* alone when using the parenthesized version - C11 draft 6.5.3.4#1/2. An understandable restriction.

Note that an expression in parenthesis after the `sizeof` keyword would have different gramatical semantics: the parenthesis are part of the expression, while for a type name, they are part of the `sizeof` operator (which would work like a function call). (I'm really not keen writing a parser for C myself.)

I for myself do normally not `typedef` pointers. That hides the semantics and supports forgetting about their somewhat special (and dangerous) properties. An exception would be an external interface where the pointer is externally used more like a handle than a pointer. But this I really only use at the outer membrane.

Ok, as I got from the discussion, you are trying to work with opaque pointers. But that will not work by defining the struct type and the pointer at once anyway. You will need to split that:

```
"hidden_stuff.h":

typedef struct HiddenStruct * const HiddenStructHandle;

"hidden_stuff.c"

#include "hidden_stuff.h"

struct HiddenStruct {
    ...
};
```

Having the struct in the header will break the encapsulation/hiding.

Comment: Isn't `(void*)0;` a valid expression ? Yet it has a type name in it.

Comment: It is an example of a valid expression with a type name in it. Consider `sizeof(void*);` if you prefer.

Comment: @RealProgrammer57: I delete my former answer and post the edited version (I was too slow to edit in 5 min - sorry)| What would be the point? we were talking about the arguments of `sizeof()`. That is a typecast. Also note the `*` being postfix, not prefix. Different semantics: `void *` is "a pointer to" void. `*foo_t` is "whatever `foo_t` points to" (dereference).

Comment: Here I am commenting the first sentence of *this answer* ("You cannot use a type name in an expression."), not the original question.

Comment: @RealProgrammer57: Point taken. I updated my answer, but are still not really happy about it. Just read the standard, You're welcome to re-phrase that sentence of mine.

Comment: sorry if i seem to be harrasing you, but your edited answer is still wrong to me. "You cannot use a type name in an expression for sizeof.". `sizeof(void*)` is valid and contains a type name. Maybe I don't understand your point. *edit* I didn't know I can edit others answer O_o, maybe I will.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57: The only thnig harassing is that you comment;-). I actually did expect you to edit the sentence. I will approve the edit if I think it does explain the idea better.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57: I edited again. The cast is actually an operator and a typename is not allowed in an expression anyway (or did I overlook something again?).

Comment: Now I don't know what "type name" means anymore ;) I give up.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57: If in doubt: read the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html/6.7.7#6.7.7). You really should that at hand ;-) The basic problem here is that a _type_ as such has no type itself (no meta-types like in HLLs like Python for instance - not sure about C++, but I suppose it is similar. So the expression `*foo_t* has no type.