# Initialize PyObject without calling __init__

Tags: python, c, cpython, python-internals

I have a wrapper class as in the example below, written in Python.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar=None):
        if bar:
            self._bar = bar
        else:
            self._bar = CreateBarObject("value")
```

I create an instance via the Python C API

```
// c++ pseudo code for convenience

auto obj = PyObject_CallObject(Foo) 
auto bar = CreateBarObject("another_value");
PyObject_SetAttrString(obj, "_bar", bar)
```

As you can see from the code, `Foo.__init__` will be called when an instance gets created which creates a new `bar` object. But I would like to bypass this "heavy" operation. So any safe way to create an instance of Foo so I can set `self._bar` via the Python C API? Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to set `_bar` through the C API? Why not just pass the `bar` object to `Foo` in the initial call?

Comment: `Foo()` with no args needs to create `self._bar` to make the instance work. But this call is a very expensive operation so I would like to bypass this cost plus bypass unnecessary byte code instructions, it needs to be a very lightweight initialization if possible

Comment: "`Foo()` with no args needs to create `self._bar` to make the instance work" - yes, so *why are you passing it no arguments*?

Comment: And what's `data`?

Comment: Because calling `__init__` and `if bar` have a significant performance impact for at least this class, so I try to optimize it. Btw, you were right, data was supposed to be `bar`. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Not really relevant to the actual question but are you writing a C++ extension or a C extension? Because `auto` seems very much like C++ because it would be weird to [use `auto` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2192547).

Comment: It's Python embedded in a c++ app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to directly invoke [the `tp_new`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_new) of `Foo` (equivalent to invoking `Foo.__new__` at the Python layer). That will perform the allocation and C level "mandatory initialization" work, without the "optional initialization" work of `tp_init`/`__init__`. It's the same strategy `pickle` uses to create instances of a type without initializing them (so it can fill them in via `__setstate__` or directly filling in `__dict__`, as appropriate).

Assuming `Foo` is a C level `PyTypeObject*`, something like this should do the trick:

```
auto emptytup = PyTuple_New(0);  /* AFAICT, the args tuple is mandatory, but kwargs is optional */
/* Error check for PyTuple_New failure */
auto obj = Foo->tp_new(Foo, emptytup, NULL);
Py_DECREF(emptytup);
/* Error check for new fail */
auto bar = CreateBarObject("another_value");
PyObject_SetAttrString(obj, "_bar", bar)
```

Answer (score -1):

Make `self.bar` a property that creates the instance the first time it's needed.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, bar=None):
        self._bar = bar

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if self._bar is None:
            self._bar = CreateBarObject(...)
        return self._bar
```

The instance is fully functional. The instance's `bar` property will create the `Bar` object the first time it's needed. Or you can set `_bar` from the C API before that, and that'll be used instead. Or you can pass in an existing `Bar` object when instantiating the class. Your choice.

Comment: Because calling `__init__` and `if bar` have a significant performance impact for at least this class I would like to get rid of the Python byte code execution in this case. But for a general approach, this is a really nice idea, never thought about that

Comment: You could just do away with `__init__` then and put an class attribute `_bar = None`. That will do away with all bytecode at `Foo` initialization.

Comment: Foo() needs to still have a `_bar` member with CreateCreateObject("value"). But I think I found a solution ShadowRanger posted. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: You've now moved the performance problem to *each* `bar` access, not just the constructor. In this case this should at least be a lazy/reify non-data descriptor.