# Is there any real life scenario where we need to explicitly specify auto keyword?

Tags: c, auto, storage-class-specifier

I am aware that by default a variable will have `auto` storage class. Then, can anyone explain me with an example where in my life i may need to explicitly specify auto keyword? If there is no such scenario, then why such a keyword is specified in the C language definition?

Comment: Because of history and backcompat.

Comment: It's a good question. (It probably seemed like a good idea at the time particularly in the days of implicit `int`.) Hope the duplicate helps. (Note that in C++ `auto` has been repurposed.)

Comment: "[A] variable" should really be "a *local non-static* variable", as `auto` have never made sense (or even worked?) on anything else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24314643/6266 seems like a reasonable explanation of the history

Comment: It's redundantly kinda like using unnecessary parenthesis in `auto double x;;;;; ... sizeof (x) ...`