# How to print the sum of int and double in C?

Tags: c, types, sum, addition, mixed

What am I doing wrong here in C, because if I run the following code I get only `0.000000` instead of `20.5`?

```
int testInt= 10;
double testDouble = 10.5;
auto testSum = testInt + testDouble;

printf("%lf\n",&testSum);
```

Comment: `printf("%lf\n", &testSum);` -> `printf("%lf\n", testSum);`, your compiler probably warned you. If not, compile with `-Wall`. Also `auto` is not a valid keyword in C, only in C++.

Comment: `auto` is not a type but storage class. Your `testSum` has a default `int` type.

Comment: Ok, than i'll not use auto, but also if i set the variable on double it doesn't work. And yes, i have also removed the & at the printf command. What do you mean with compile with -Wall?

Comment: @Codemaster2022 so does it work as expected if you remove the `&` in front of `testSum`?

Comment: As @EugeneSh. said the type for `testSum` is `int` by default. So you must use the `%d` type in `printf`. I.e. `printf("%d\n", testSum);`. If you want use doubles then define it as: `double testSum`, then `printf("%lf\n", testSum);` can be used.

Comment: No, it just doesn't work. Whyever

Comment: Why is it that when I write the code with the modifications that you said you have done, it works for me?

Comment: Yes, but then i get 20 as resoult instead of 20.5 . And i'd like to mixed up the different types

Comment: Cheatah, really? No it really dont work for me

int testInt = 10;
double testDouble = 10.5;
int testSum = testInt + testDouble;

 printf("%lf\n", testSum);

Comment: Oh, i have found the mistake i had to write double test sum not int testsum. Now it works!

Comment: @Codemaster2022 before I wrote "also `auto` is not a valid keyword in C, only in C++": this is not quite true. `auto testSum = testInt + testDouble;` is actually valid in C, but it does not what you think it does. In C++ `auto` lets the compiler deduce the type automatically depending on the type of the expression on the right side of the `=`. Here that type is `double`. But in C `auto testSum = testInt + testDouble;` is equivalent to `testSum = testInt + testDouble;` which in turn is equivalent to `int testSum = testInt + testDouble;` in this case.

Comment: @Codemaster2022  Read more about the (useless and almost never used auto keyword in C) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192547/where-is-the-c-auto-keyword-used

Comment: @Jabberwocky: `auto testSum = testInt + testDouble;` is not equivalent to `testSum = testInt + testDouble;`. The former is a declaration. The latter is a statement.